# indexedDB-reading cursor using field name

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I've many small tables under IndexedDB, each to create a select in my HTML page.
So let's say one is created with:

```
        store_dest_fam.createIndex("tdestf_id", "tdestf_id", { unique: true });
        store_dest_fam.createIndex("tdestf_nom", "tdestf_nom", { unique: false });
```

a second one is:

```
        store_frota.createIndex("tfrota_id", "tfrota_id", { unique: true });
        store_frota.createIndex("tfrota_nom", "tfrota_nom", { unique: false });
```

If I create a function for each, in order to read value using "cursor" I build a loop in which I have:

```
        var tdestf_id = cursor.value.tdestf_id;
        var tdestf_nom = cursor.value.tdestf_nom;
```

and so on. That's OK.

But as I've many small tables, I want to create a "global function", with parameters like:

```
           make_select(name_of_table,name_for_value,name_for_text);
```

with for example:

```
  name_of_table = "TAB_START";     // Name of the table to search in
  name_for_value = "tdestf_id";    // Name of the field which value would be use as "value" in the select-option
  name_for_text = "tdestf_text";    // Name of the field which value would be use as "text" in the select-option
```

I can open the connection to the table using

```
    var tx_menu = db_handle.transaction(name_of_table, 'readonly');
    var store_menu = tx_menu.objectStore(name_of_table);
```

which is logical as db_handle.transaction wait for the "string name" of the table, which is what i'm providing. But in the cursor loop this don't work (which seem to be logical as curso need a pointer to its structure while I'm providing a string)

```
    var data_value = cursor.value.name_for_value;
    var data_text = cursor.value.name_for_text;
```

So th question is: how can I get the cursor item value, giving the "string name" of the field?

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking how to dynamically access cursor.value.somethinghere? If so, you can use bracket notation. Assuming your asked for a fields tsestf_id and tdestgf_text and passed them as valueField and textField:

```
var data_value = cursor.value[valueField];
var data_text = cursor.value[textField];
```

Comment: So easy! I was convinced to have tested this option but apparently it was not the case. Thank you!